# How could I code a variable in an image tag a Simpler way?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I may want to display different versions of charts of the SAME stock symbol so it needs using "var".
 (Other uses I have are weather charts or traffic cams etc, so I have broader applications). 
I'll illustrate it with stock charts.

By trial and error I found using the id="x" and "document.getElementById" works, 
but it needs careful bookkeeping of the SAME and unique id TWICE on each line. (Breaking the line instead of a "long line" makes it even harder to keep id's straight)

Imagine with dozens of additional lines of chart variations it becomes tedious.

Is there a better way?  How would you code it to produce a "collage of graphs"?

```html
<script> var sym = "MSFT" </script> 

<h1><strong> <body> Symbol <script> document.write(sym); </script></body><br> 


<img src="" id="i1">$ <script> var a = document.getElementById('i1'); a.src = "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=o&tlf=12h&q=" + sym ; </script> &nbsp;&nbsp;

<img src="" id="i2">% <script> var a = document.getElementById('i2'); a.src = "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=c&tlf=12h&q=" + sym ; </script> &nbsp;&nbsp;
<!-- etc.  perhaps dozens more different charts for the same symbol -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove all of the `<script>` tags from inside the HTML. This keeps document structure and behavioral logic separate. Here's an example using a loop and string concatenation that should be expandible:

```
<h1 id="title"></h1>
<img src="" class="symbol" alt="stock chart">$&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="" class="symbol" alt="stock chart">%&nbsp;&nbsp;
<!-- etc.  perhaps dozens more different charts for the same symbol -->

<script>

const sym = "MSFT";
const urls = [
  "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=o&tlf=12h&q=", 
  "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=c&tlf=12h&q="
];
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Symbol " + sym;
const symElems = document.getElementsByClassName("symbol");

for (let i = 0; i < symElems.length; i++) {
  symElems[i].src = urls[i] + sym; 
}

</script>
```

You might want to use an object instead of an array for the URLs, and add ids to your `<img>` tags depending on your needs. The problem with not using a class name is that it might be easier to lose track of how many elements are in the collection you're manipulating (not to mention styling). You may also wish to dynamically generate the `<img>` elements using `document.createElement("img")` and set the properties in JS:

```
<h1 id="title"></h1>
<div id="sym-container"></div>

<script>

const sym = "MSFT";
const urls = [
  "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=o&tlf=12h&q=", 
  "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=c&tlf=12h&q=",
  "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=g&tlf=12h&q=",
  "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=s&tlf=12h&q=" 
];
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Symbol " + sym;
const symContainer = document.getElementById("sym-container");

urls.forEach(e => {
  const symElem = document.createElement("img");
  symElem.src = e + sym; 
  symContainer.appendChild(symElem);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks much more elegant.  I especially like the last snippet where it is a clear list.  I have to study it harder, though, as the chart urls might look completely different and symbols not necessarily at the end.  e.g. to demonstrate just even a slight variation (comparing to the S&P500) http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=c&tlf=12h&q=MSFT,.INX  I can not simply add a line "http://www.google.com/finance/chart?cht=c&tlf=12h&q=.INX", . I am only learning now about using objects etc you suggested.

Comment: Trying out more examples I a really impressed how well it works, always correct when the sym is at the end of the url.  This helps me greatly! Now I have to figure out how to construct the line or code when the const is somewhere in the middle for some urls and at the end for others, say pretend one would have to be "...q=MSFT,.INX"  others just "... q=MSFT"

Comment: Sounds good--let me know if you need more guidance. It's a matter of finding the right data structure to hold whatever information you are going to need (maybe JSON if it's a lot), writing a loop, concatenating strings, and sticking elements into the document. If you have wide variations between each URL you want to build or other specifications, it might take a bit more fussing.